# Initializing array of Objects in C++ Composition

Tags: c++

I wanted to design a `composition` using `C++` as shown below:

```cpp
#define NUMBER (4)

class wheel {
    int radius;
public:
    wheel();
    wheel(int);
    //copy constructors prototype
    //getters and setters prototypes
};

wheel::wheel() : radius(1) {}
wheel::wheel(int r) : radius(r) {}
//wheel class copy constructor definition
//wheel class setter and getter definitions

class car {
    wheel fourwheels[NUMBER];
public:
    car();
};

car::car() {
    fourwheels[NUMBER] = {wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1)};            //error code
    //wheel fourwheels[NUMBER] = {wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1)};    //non-error code
}

int main() {
    car mycar;
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling the code, I am getting the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'wheel' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
```

**Queries:**

1. Why does this error occur ??
2. When I comment the `error code` line and uncomment the `non-error code` line, it works fine. Why do we have to add the type `wheel` for the array definition?

Comment: Unrelated, but perhaps a sign of a design-flaw: `fourwheels[NUMBER]` - see the redundancy? How many wheels can a `fourwheels` have?

Comment: I know.... I am dumb!! hahah!! :D

Comment: Not at all! Just a "fun" finding. :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to assign to an array element. And one that's out of range at that.

Using the constructor's initializer list, this will compile, though you should consider using STL containers rather than a raw array.

```
car::car() : fourwheels{wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1)}
{
}
```

The code you had commented out "worked" because it declared and initialized a *new* array of four wheels.

Since the default constructor for `wheel` provides a radius of `1`, you could also write:

```
car::car() : fourwheels{wheel(), wheel(), wheel(), wheel()}
{
}
```

---

But, if we used `std::array` to hold our wheels, we can simplify this further, as the elements of `fourwheels` will be initialized using the `wheel` type's default constructor, which we don't have to write.

```
class car {
    std::array<wheel, NUMBER> fourwheels;
};
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain to on what you mean by "Assign to an array element" and "Out of Range at that" ?? :)

Comment: If I declare an array of ints, for instance, `int arr[4]`, then when I use `arr[4] = ...` I am assigning to index `4` in `arr`. Since C++ arrays are indexed starting at `0`, `4` is the _fifth_ index and is out of bounds.

Comment: Oh Okay. Makes sense now. I get it. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Hi Chris. How do I write Copy Constructor for the Car class??? Kindly help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this error occur ??

Raw arrays are not copy-assignable.  That is, the following will not work:

```
int nums[4] = {};
nums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

That is essentially what you're trying to do in your `car` constructor.  Instead, you need to *initialize* the `fourwheels` member in the member initialization list:

```
car::car()
  : fourwheels{wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1), wheel(1)}
{}
```

> When I comment the `error code` line and uncomment the `non-error code` line, it works fine. Why do we have to add the type `wheel` for the array definition ??

Because you're not initializing your `car` class's member there.  You're declaring and initializing a *different* array, also named `fourwheels` that is local to the constructor body.  The class member remains default-initialized.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. So my class member is a raw array when I create and object and I create a local array in my constructor's body with the same name. Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe another query!! Are "int num[4];" and "int num[4]={};" the same?? Are they both raw arrays??

Comment: Those expressions both declare an array of 4 `int`s.  The former leaves the elements uninitialized, while the latter will 0-initialize all of the elements.